# Disable selection in PrimeFaces DataTable during load

Tags: java, html, jsf, primefaces

I have a PrimeFaces DataTable. When I click an entry (selectionMode="single") I'm loading some data and show the user a loading text. The loading text is set visible / unvisible with a JS function. Now I have the problem that I want to disable the selectionMode until the data for the clicked event are loaded to avoid multiple requests at the same time. Do you have any ideas how to deal with this?

It would be an option to disable the selectionMode when the loading text is set to visible and enable it when the text is set to unvisible. Is this possible? If not, how can I do this instead of JS?

Comment: PF has components for this. `p:blockui`. Check their docs and showcase

Comment: Normally PF ajax calls are serialized, and you won't get "multiple" requests, meaning a new request before the previous has finished.